# Combine rows that have common elements

Tags: r

I have a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) that looks like this:

```r
# Load packages
library(data.table)

# Set RNG seed
set.seed(-1)

# Create dummy data
dt <- data.table(foo = sample(letters[1:10], 6),
                 bar = sample(letters[1:10], 6))

dt
#>    foo bar
#> 1:   g   a
#> 2:   h   j
#> 3:   j   e
#> 4:   a   i
#> 5:   d   g
#> 6:   i   c
```

I would like to group together all associated elements. What I mean by that is, for example, `a` and `g` are together in the first row, so they belong together in a group (`a`, `g`). But `a` and `i` are together on row 4, so `i` also belongs to this group (`a`, `g`, `i`). Also, `i` is associated with `c` on row 6, so `c` also belongs to the group (`a`, `g`, `i`, `c`). On row 5, `d` and `g` are together, so `d` also belongs to this group (`a`, `g`, `i`, `c`, `d`).

Applying this logic gives the following desired result.

```r
# Desired result
# [[1]]
# [1] a c d g i
# [[2]]
# [1] e h j
```

I have some code that achieves this result, but nesting a `mapply` in a `while` loop together with some really clunky handling of data structures makes me think that this is far from optimal.

```r
# Loop counter
i <- 1

# List of groups
res <- list()

while(nrow(dt)>0){
  # Add first row to list
  res[[i]] <- unlist(dt[1])

  # Check each row in dt
  mapply(function(x, y){

    # If there are common elements between current row and current group
    if(length(intersect(c(x, y), res[[i]])) > 0){
      # Add elements from this row to this group
      res[[i]] <<- c(res[[i]], x, y)
    }

  }, dt$foo, dt$bar)

  # Only keep unique elements
  res[[i]] <- unique(res[[i]])

  # Remove rows that have elements in the current group
  dt <- dt[!(foo %in% res[[i]] | bar %in% res[[i]])]

  # Increment loop counter
  i <- i + 1
}
```

gives,

```r
res
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "g" "a" "i" "d" "c"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "h" "j" "e"
```

as required.

Is there a more elegant and efficient way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data could be considered as a graph with components of different connectivity. To analyze this kind of data you could use the library `igraph`:

Simply create a graph from your data frame of edges:

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

set.seed(-1)

foo = sample(letters[1:10], 6)
bar = sample(letters[1:10], 6)

edges <- data.table(foo, bar)

net <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, directed = F)
```

You can then find the isolated components of the graph:

```
components(net)

# $membership
# g h j a d i e c 
# 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 
#
# $csize
# [1] 5 3
#
# $no
# [1] 2
```

Or get a nicer list of the vertices contained in each component:

```
split(names(V(net)), components(net)$membership)
# $`1`
# [1] "g" "a" "d" "i" "c"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "h" "j" "e"
```

Comment: That's a really clean solution and I like the perspective of viewing it as a graph.